# How to launch an action when return is a certain value

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I use the returned value (response) for launching a specific action?

Can I do something like :

```
$( "#return" ).on( "text=XXX", function() {
```

Here is my ajax post query :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post.php",
        data: {code: data},
        success: function(response) {
            $("#log").hide();
            $("#logIntro").hide();
            $("#return").show().text(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#log").hide();
            $("#logIntro").hide();
            $("#return").show().text('Connexion error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use "e" as a name, it is universally used as "event" and is hugely confusing

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem but I know you're right. Thank you anyway

Comment: Just use an if: `if (response === "text=XXX") ....` or `const res = JSON.parse(response); if (res.test === "XXX") ...`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a condition.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php",
    data: {code: data},
    success: function(event) {
        $("#log").hide();
        $("#logIntro").hide();
        $("#return").show().text(event);
        if (event == "test"){
            // Test content
            $("#1").text('X');
            $("#1").on("click", function() {});
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        $("#log").hide();
        $("#logIntro").hide();
        $("#return").show().text('Erreur de connexion');
    }
});
```